# MySql DataBase's current datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have to compare a Date time with the current format date time of my MySQL database, but the problem is that I don't know how to get that format from my database. For some reason, when I insert a date time into the database, it automatically converts it to another format changing the hours and minutes. For example, if I want to insert '12:05:26', it changes to '17:10:30'. I want to compare the two formats to validate what I'm inserting.

Comment: Please do add a sample of code, how exactly your database is set up (column definition) and potential additional information about how you actually (in code) try to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's mixing the time and date on the insert? Could be due to the fact that your database uses different language settings that the formatted date you're inserting. Try explicitly parsing the date with STR_TO_DATE() function on Insert to avoid messing up.

```
INSERT INTO someTable (someDateTime) VALUES
(STR_TO_DATE('22/03/2017 9:30:20 AM', '%c/%e/%Y %r'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `DATE_FORMAT` function to format a MySQL `DATE` or `DATETIME` value into a string of a specified format. For example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%a, %M %e, %Y')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

---

What exactly is the "it" that is doing the format conversion? The observed behavior is probably explainable, but without seeing the code or statements that is producing this behavior, we're just guessing.

How is it that you are determining that MySQL is changing the values you supply?

---

MySQL has a standard format for datetime strings: `%Y-%m-%d %T`.

MySQL does allow some latitude in the formats it accepts.  The reference manual notes

> MySQL permits a "relaxed" format...

and also gives warning that colons are not necessarily reserved for time, those can be used and interpreted as separators for date values. Not that we would ever really want to do this:

```
   SELECT '2017:3:21-16_35_11' + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

MySQL will also recognize numeric values (with two digit month, day, hour, minute second). `yyyymmddhhmmss`, e.g.

```
  SELECT 20170321163511 + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

To support various string formats, MySQL provides the handy `DATE_FORMAT` and `STR_TO_DATE` functions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

---

```
 CREATE TABLE foo (dt DATETIME PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=INNODB;
 INSERT INTO foo (dt) VALUES ('2017-03-21 12:05:26');
 SELECT dt FROM foo;
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%T') FROM foo; 
 DROP TABLE foo;
```